# objective c - Display activity indicator when parsing an xml on tableview cell click

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml-parsing, uiactivityindicatorview

I am a beginner in iOS programming. I am creating a tableview where, on click of each cell a different xml gets parsed. I want to show a activity indicator when xml is parsing and stop that indicator when parsing is finished. my code is,

//Activity Indicator
    //in viewDidLoad,

```
    activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
    activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 20.0, 20.0);
    activityIndicator.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0f green:0/255.0f blue:0/255.0f alpha:0.5];
    activityIndicator.center=self.view.center;
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    [self.view addSubview:activityIndicator];

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(cell.accessoryView==nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"index path is %i",indexPath.row+1);
        cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_selected.png"]];
        [myObj1 changecheckedvalue:1 forindex:[[tempArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]mainID]];

        if (indexPath.row==0)
        {
            flagToCheck=1;
            xmlName=@"Pournima";
            [parseArray removeAllObjects];
            [self xmlParsing];
        }
   }
}
```

How to achieve that? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this one : https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD
It has a better look and feel.

Start the activity indicator before calling the method for parsing in "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" and stop it at the end of the method for parsing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) to display an activity view that sits on top the current view. The library is quite easy to use and implement. You would just import MBProgressHUD.h, and then call this method:

```
[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
```

or if you want to show an activity view inside cell, maybe next to title, you could use something like,

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
[cell.imageView addSubview:activityView];
[activityView startAnimating];
```

you would then remove the activityView from its superview when you are done.